# Working with the to-do list in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to work with the built in to-do list in WP7? I noticed that if you show your to-dos in the calendar then `Appointments.SearchASync()` will also bring them but without subject nor notes, which renders it pretty much useless.

An online service I could link my phone to that also provided an open API would also be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Calendars (Live Connect API)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx)

I fear , Currently , You can't create or edit to do lists in windows phone 7 via SDK .

Comment: I'm not sure if the Live Connect API also allows me to query for to-do items, since they're handled in a separated tab other than the calendar and don't appear in the calendar either.